# SharePoint list change status based on today's date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have SharePoint list with this data:
Task name, start date, end date, due date, status.

Status is calculated column with IF clause to change status accordingly to tasks' dates based on today's date:

```
=IF([End Date]="";IF([Start Date]>TODAY();"Not started";IF(AND([Start Date]<=TODAY();[Due Date]>TODAY();[Due Date]>TODAY()+14);"In progress";IF(AND([Due Date]>=TODAY();[Due Date]<=TODAY()+14);"Approaching";"Late")));IF([End Date]<=[Due Date];"Finished on time";IF([End Date]>[Due Date];"Finished with delay";"false")))
```

The problem is that SharePoint doesn't refresh the status, when the today date changes.
In this case I have to resave status column in list settings to make SharePoint to change all tasks' statuses.

Maybe there is a smarter way of doing it?

I am using SharePoint SE and can't use power apps. Column or list formatting is also not an option because I need to have statuses' values in the list to use it with Datatable.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that SharePoint doesn't refresh the status, when the today date changes.

Calculated columns in SharePoint are ...calculated (when a change is made on the item). So, this is the **expected behavior** as the calculated values do not change automatically everyday (and calculated is not limited to dates).

You can use however filtered views with `Today` or `Now` to compare with the start date / end date columns. So you can visualize items not started, in progress, late, etc.

Samples:

- [Creating a Dynamic [Today] Filtered View in SharePoint to show “Recent Stuff”](https://donnasresources.com/how-to-create-a-dynamic-today-filtered-view-in-sharepoint/)
- [Using today’s date and/or current time in calculated columns and list view filters](https://natechamberlain.com/2018/03/04/using-todays-date-and-or-current-time-in-calculated-columns-and-list-view-filters/)
- [SharePoint - Use Today's Date Time in list view filter and calculated column](https://code2care.org/q/sharepoint-online-today-date-time-list-view-filter-calculated-column-field/)